# NHibernate and batch-size

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I wanted to ask how you guys in general use `batch-size` within the mappings. Do you in general set a certain number on any mapped collection? Of course, I do know about the other fetching strategies like `join fetch`, but sometimes I have to filter during post processing, which might trigger lot's of lazy loading. I figured out if I set the batch-size e.g. to 100, I have much better performance in such cases.

**Do you set this property in general on any mapped collection?** If not, why not? Could there be any disadvantage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `batch-size` on collections or on parent entities are going to pretty much do the same thing.

What `batch-size` is really doing is taking a `SELECT N+1` issue and turning that into a `SELECT N/batch-size + 1` condition.

There is an disadvantage and that is you need to balance the difference between setting the right number. If you make batch-size too large, you will load too much data, if you make it too small, you will still have too many queries. How you balance this is open for debate and without setting up testing is impossible to measure.

I consider this as a micro optimisation, important as it can really reduce the select/n+1 problem. However it really isn't as important as selecting the correct fetching strategy for each scenario independently, this makes for a better strategy overall.

I also think of this as a production issue and should be tested against real users against real data.

As a side note I always set my `batch-size` to be equal to my paging size, don't ask me why it just feels right!

Comment: How can too much data be loaded? It need's to be loaded anyhow. As far as I `batch-size` understand, it only groups the many different queries and sends it at once to the database.

Comment: maybe/maybe not, if you are not using all the collections that you have referenced e.g. you retrieve 1000 Comments, but you only show the comments for the first 25 you will be loading data unnecessarily. Also  a query with a lot of parameters `might` be harder on the DB than a few smaller queries. That's why I recommended setting up testing

Comment: Ah - I thought if I define lazy="true", batch-size won't trigger anything if the data is not accessed in the code? I wouldn't expect Hinbernate to load anything in that case unnecessarily...

Comment: correct, but if you DO trigger lazy loading and having a batch-size of 1000 will load upto 1000 children in one BIG SQL statement